# On $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\operatorname{frac}\left(\frac{1}{\operatorname{gd}(x)}\right)dx$, where $\operatorname{gd}(x)$ is the Gudermannian function

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, fractional-part

Let $\operatorname{gd}(x)$ the Gudermannian function, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html). And we denote with $ \left\{ x \right\} =\operatorname{frac}(x)$ the fractional part function that satisfies $$x=\left\{ x \right\} +\lfloor x\rfloor.$$

> **Question.** How can you deduce if this integral $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\left\{ \frac{1}{\operatorname{gd}(x)} \right\}dx$$ is convergent or divergent? **Many thanks.**

I know that $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\operatorname{gd}(x)}dx$$ does not converge, and that  it is possible to write the integrand involving different functions, see previous reference.

Comment: Also I know that $$0\leq\left\{ \text{something} \right\} <1.$$ I would like to know a rigurous proof to deduce if our integral is convergent or divergent. Many thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. If you want feel free to add your previous comment as an answer. Thus only is required rewrite your hints @Winther

Comment: Many thanks @ss1729, but in the title $\operatorname{frac}(z)$ means the fractional part function $ \left\{ z \right\} $, I wanted write it to emphasize and make a self-contained title. Any case, many thanks and good week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\text{gd}(x) \sim x$ as $x\to 0$ so the integral is divergent by a comparison with the integral
$$\int_{0}^1\frac{1}{x}\left\{\frac{1}{x}\right\}{\rm d}x \underbrace{=}_{\text{substitution } u = \frac{1}{x}} \int_1^\infty \frac{\{u\}}{u}{\rm d}u = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} \frac{x-n}{x}{\rm d}x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 - n\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)$$
which diverges by comparison to the harmonic series as $1 - n\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right) \sim \frac{1}{2n}$. for $n\to\infty$

Comment: Thanks I am going to take it in my notebook now. On the other hand I asked myself that maybe do you would to know an interview in english with title *Conoce a un candidato a Premio Nobel: Barry Barish (parte 1/2)*, and also see *(parte 2/2)*, from the official channel in YouTube of the [Instituto de Física Teórica IFT](https://www.youtube.com/user/IFTMadrid). I hope don't disturb, it is a recent interview to Barry Barish, and maybe you or your colleagues want to see it. Isn't required a response of this comment, good week.